# python selenium all test in one session browser

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, webdriver

I have a question.

I have 10 classes in 10 files and one main class and class with user log.
I run all tests in the main class. I would like to run 10 at once. At present, the browser opens up to 10 times with each class.
I would like 10 tests to take place in 1 browser session.
It is possible? Because I can not do this. Please, help me, thank you! Me login class:

```
class Login(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def setUp(self):
    self.browser.get("www")
    username = self.browser.find_element_by_id("username")
    password = self.browser.find_element_by_id("password")
    username.send_keys("aaaa")
    password.send_keys("ssswww")
    self.browser.find_element_by_id("button").click()

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.get("about:blank")

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.browser.quit()
```

Comment: Can you use `pytest`? If so, this should be easy to do with a [properly scoped fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session).

Comment: Yes i can. Can you help me how change my code to pytest?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like 10 tests to take place in 1 browser session.

This code will open one browser and then use it for multiple tests. [I'm not sure that this is the best way to do selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6563725/8079103) and you may want to clear cookies as shown in the accepted answer there but I'll leave that to you.

```
import time

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


# if you omit `scope='module'`, every test will open a new browser
# this way it will use the same browser for each test
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver():
    d = webdriver.Chrome()
    # d.get("www")
    # username = d.find_element_by_id("username")
    # password = d.find_element_by_id("password")
    # username.send_keys("aaaa")
    # password.send_keys("ssswww")
    # d.find_element_by_id("button").click()
    yield d
    d.quit()


@pytest.mark.parametrize('url', (
    'https://google.com',
    'https://yahoo.com',
    'https://bing.com',
))
def test_hmm(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    assert True
```

Console:

```
$ pytest hmm.py
======================================================= test session starts ========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/lettuce/Dropbox/Python/Python_3, inifile:
plugins: hypothesis-3.46.0
collected 3 items                                                                                                                  

hmm.py ...                                                                                                                   [100%]

==================================================== 3 passed in 15.34 seconds =====================================================
```

Comment: In my class when I created webdriver i need make this class with pytest? And second in mark parameteize i set www where i start my test?

Comment: @Tom1416 It's really difficult for me to answer questions about your code which I can't see. This is a working example of re-using a fixture (in this case, a selenium driver) between multiple tests. I only used `parametrize` to have a short example of multiiple tests. `pytest` mostly uses functions for tests ([it is still possible to group them under classes if necessary](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class)). Here is an example with those tests broken up: https://bpaste.net/show/1bafc34586ed

Comment: @Tom1416 Here is an example of grouping those separate tests inside a class: https://bpaste.net/show/f31fb75b6dff

Answer (score 0):

[capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py), which provides a layer on top of Selenium, uses a single browser session, taking care of the necessary cleanup for you:

```py
import capybara

class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.page = capybara.dsl.page
        self.page.visit("http://www.example.com")
        self.page.fill_in("Username", value="aaaa")
        self.page.fill_in("Password", value="ssswww")
        self.page.click_button("Sign in")

    def tearDown(self):
        capybara.reset_sessions()
```

Comment: How Can I add capybara library to my project? I download Capybara, I add this to project but not work,

Comment: @Tom1416 You should add it to your project the same way you added the `selenium` package.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_anew_user.py", line 5, in <module>
    from login import LoginTest
  File "/home/tom/download/test-project-browser/login.py", line 3, in <module>
    import capybara
  File "/home/tom/download/test-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capybara/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .capybara import Capybara
  File "/home/tom/download/test-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capybara/capybara.py", line 5, in <module>
    from amazon_wrapper import AmazonWrapper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amazon_wrapper'

Comment: My problem, I can't start any test, because amazon_wrapper not found

Comment: Install `capybara-py`.

Comment: Yes, I install and problem is the same.

Comment: Uninstall the `capybara` project you installed before. It’s likely conflicting with `capybara-py`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, or maybe I should create a new project and first install capybara in pycharm and then copy my file ? Please write my command how i must install this.

Comment: That depends on how you manage your Python project dependencies and is pretty far outside of the scope of this question and answer. There are plenty of guides and tutorials on the internet that cover how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize Chrome webdriver inside your `Login` class, instead of initializing it in the `setUp()` class. This way, the browser will open once for each test.